# could not create server file "c:/myimage.jpg" using postgreSQL lo_export and delphi 7

Tags: image, delphi, postgresql

im using Postgres 9.0 to save images into the database using 'lo_import' and 
to export images using lo_export with an application using delphi 7.

everything works fine on my system but if i try the lo_export on other system i get an error

[image]

the  query im using is 
'SELECT lo_export(fishimages.imagevalue,'c:/leeUpdate.jpg') from  fishimages where fishname=meckeral';

but it gives error on other systems and not mine.!!!

Comment: does the postgres service have write access on other systems? you're trying to save to C drive, so I assume the write access is denied.

Comment: It may be a user rights problem (the user used by PostGresSQL server service) or a filenamesyntax one : may be change 'c:/' to 'c:\'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a write access problem. You are trying to create a file in a folder (which is C root in this case) without having a write access permission. Change the folder to a place which your SQL user has write access to or give your SQL user a write access to c:\

Comment: Yes, your reply is perfect...the write access permission is the problem,
so a good place for exporting is i think
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents

here it worked on other systems perfectly 

thanks Emir Akaydın :)